# Weil algebras as infinitesimal ring extensions?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, synthetic-differential-geometry

I'm trying to get comfortable with concepts from synthetic differential geometry. I was wondering whether the structure of a Weil algebra is somehow related to the general notion of an *infinitesimal extension* of a ring, which is a (regular?) epi $\hat R\twoheadrightarrow R$ with nilpotent kernel.

The structure of a Weil algebra is still mostly opaque to me, but this general notion of an infinitesimal extension looks very intuitive, so I'm hoping for a simple link..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weil algebras over $k$ are infinitesimal extensions of $k$.

Comment: What is it that makes them so special?

Comment: @Arrow: mapping into them is a way to get at "generalized tangent spaces." For example, take $R$ to just be a commutative $k$-algebra. Then maps $R \to k$ correspond to $k$-points. Maps $R \to k[x]/x^2$ correspond to Zariski tangent vectors at $k$-points. Maps $R \to k[x]/x^3$ correspond to jets of order $2$ at $k$-points. Etc.

Comment: @Arrow: it would help if you told me which definition of Weil algebra you're using. The definition I found is just the above definition, so it's clear what the relationship to infinitesimal extensions is.

Comment: Sorry, this is all new territory for me. The definition I've seen is an augmented $R$-algebra of finite dimension whose ideal of augmentation is nilpotent.

Comment: @Arrow: isn't it clear that these are infinitesimal extensions of $R$ then? I don't really understand your confusion.

Comment: Yes, that much is clear, but I though Weil algebras are very special such extensions. That 'mapping into them is a way to get "generalized tangent spaces"' is probably what I was looking for. I don't understand what that means yet, but I have a vague picture. Thanks.